# How do I detect the 'strict' pragma within a module?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Normally when I build a data structure in Perl, I end up having to declare it from `%leaf` to `%root`, so I have been tinkering with a module that would allow me to build up from 
 
`$seed` to `$seed->trunk->branch->leaf`.

It's not difficult with `AUTOLOAD` and `new` subroutines.  My question for SO is how do I detect if the 'strict' pragma is in use, so that the module runs in a different mode that would require the variables to be "declared" before usage so I don't accidently assign a value to `$seed->drunk` when I'm using strict -- assume that the module is called `branch` and this is valid syntax for module usage

```
$seed->declare('trunk');
$seed->trunk(new branch);

$seed->trunk->declare('leaf');
$seed->trunk->leaf("value");
```

How do I detect if the strict pragma is in effect in the calling program from the module?

It may be that this is not possible -- in which case I'd have to use a static variable to handle module independent pragmas.

EDITED / POSTSCRIPT:

I coded out the initial version that doesn't check for 'strictness' or implement a 'declare' subroutine and realized that the autoloader would not provide a simple enough user syntax if it operated by reference, so I wrote it to check for the first parameter and assign the value passed to an element in the object's referred hash table, otherwise if there was no parameter it would return the value of the element specified.

So I am posting the code for the branch module to satisfy your curiosity.  Mind you, I haven't implemented a check for strictness, yet.

```
package branch;

sub new
{
    my $type = shift;
    my $self = { };
    bless $self, $type;
    return $self;
}

sub DESTROY
{
    my $self = shift;
    %$self = undef;
}

sub AUTOLOAD
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $value = shift;

    my $sub = $AUTOLOAD;
    my ($type, $PROGRAM) = ($sub =~ /(.*)::(.*)/);

    if( $value ne undef )
    {
        $$self{$PROGRAM} = $value;
        return $value;
    }
    return $$self{$PROGRAM};
}

1;
```

Comment: Detect if it's in effect where? Strictures aren't global.

Comment: Your question appears to be missing some important context and playing loose with terminology. You mention declaring variables but `$seed->trunk` is a method call. (Apparently it returns an lvalue, or you wouldn't be able to assign to it.) I *think* that 1) you're wrapping a data structure in an OO interface, 2) you're using AUTOLOAD to automatically generate accessors, and 3) you want to prevent AUTOLOAD from creating an accessor for attributes that haven't been predeclared. Is that right?

Comment: and what's wrong with that?  I described my justification for doing so and I already found the answer that I needed.

Comment: @JustKevin: I was just seeking clarification. Unclear questions are difficult to answer and unlikely to be useful to anyone else who might be having a similar problem. (Helping everyone -- not just the original poster -- is the purpose of SO.) I was also attempting to tease out whether or not this was an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If the question was about the data structure or the accessor function I would have written it that way.  I would suggest that if it was not immediately apparent that it was an XY problem, it isn't.  Don't try to corner me into formulating a logical contradiction.

Comment: @JustKevin you're being a dick. Try not being a dick.

Comment: at least I have a good sense of humor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the first thing would be, strict *what*? Strict has three subpragmas, with their own behaviors and bits to check. `use strict 'refs'` doesn't allow you to dereference strings; `use strict 'vars'` doesn't allow you to access global variables in an unqualified way, and `use strict 'subs'` disables barewords outside of a few situations. `use strict` equates to all three, but none of them really seems close enough to what you're asking for to be worth piggy-backing on.

So to answer your question somewhat directly: element `[8]` in the list returned by `caller($i)` returns the compile hint bits in effect for the `$i`th level caller. If you peek in `strict.pm` you can see the bits that each subpragma sets and check for them at the caller level that corresponds to the code that's actually calling your method.

But, returning to my original point, you probably shouldn't, because that's not what strict is about. You should either accept an option on your objects' constructor that decides whether they should behave strictly or not, or if you *really* want a lexical pragma instead of something that follows your objects around, you should write your own using the information in [perlpragma](http://p3rl.org/perlpragma) as a tutorial. All perls since 5.10 support arbitrary user-defined pragmas using the `%^H` hints hash which is exposed as element `[10]` of the caller info.

Comment: The point was that I want the objects that I instantiate to inherit 'strictness' from the calling program and behave accordingly; with the AUTOLOAD routine carrying responsiblity for handling data storage the package was circumventing <code>strict 'vars'</code>  I think this is exactly the answer that I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confused about the scoping of the strict pragma.

If a module uses strict, this doesn't enforce anything on the user of the module. Even if you want to extend the package, by subclassing or monkey-patching in additional methods.

`use strict` only applies to the *file* it is used within. (Or if it's used within a pair of curly braces, it only applies up until the closing brace.) So if you're extending a package, just do it within a separate file, and none of the pragmas applied in the original module will apply to your code.

---

That said, it's rarely a good idea to *not* `use strict`. There are occasional tasks where it might be useful to disable it in a small scope, but the problem you are describing doesn't seem to be one of them.

In particular, if you're building a deeply nested structure, only don't need to declare every level. Demonstration:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $root;
$root->{trunk}{branch}{leaf} = 42;

print Dumper($root);
```

Comment: I think you have missed the point of what the OP wants to do. He wants his own module to obey the semantics of 'strict' (which he defines)  if the code that is calling his module has strict in force.